# Why won't my subclass of UITableViewCells appear when run?

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

When I wireframe it, the cell is nested above the TableView. My project structure is that I have a main view controller and a subclass of a TableView that's also using a TableViewCell that I subclassed. Everything is in place, I have no idea why it's not showing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var tv: TaskTableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    }
```

My subclass of UITableView.

```
import UIKit

class TaskTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    var title: String = ""
    var detail: String = ""
    var time: NSDate = NSDate()
    var data = ["asdf","asdf","sadf"]

    init(frame: CGRect, title: String, detail: String, time: NSDate)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.detail = detail
        self.time = time
        super.init(frame: frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)


    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return data.count
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NewTVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "toDoCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toDoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTVCell
        cell.title.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: Did you set the storyboard's custom tableview to the custom tableview class? Same goes to the tableviewcell

Comment: Yes and yes. I set those properties in the storyboard

Comment: Did you set the table view as its own `dataSource` and `delegate` in the storyboard?